# MS Project Auto Schedule

Tags: ms-project

I am using MS project 2016. My project plan has 700 line items all of them are scheduled **auto schedule**. 
My issue is that Manual Schedule or Auto Schedule Button is *greyed* out. I have multiple dependencies. I have dependencies, but those dependencies don't seem to work.

For example, When changing the duration, it does update the finish date, but it does not update the start date of the successors, even though I have a Finish to start dependency mapped. How can "reactivate" my mapped dependencies? 
Example row 16, if I change the duration to 10 days it does not automatically update row 17. Do you know why?

I have made sure that I do not have any constraints and that all activities are auto scheduled, but that does not work. 
I am not sure if this is an issue: but MS project opens ins compatibility mode. Also when I delete the 500 lines of the 700 lines, dependencies of the remaining 200 lines work...

Attached a picture of a couple of line items of the project plan where I have deleted the content of "**names**" for confidentiality reasons.
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Badnz.png)
Thanks

Comment: How can I upoad the whole MS project plan?

Comment: FYI: As this is not a programming question, it belongs in a different forum--either the Project Management one or SuperUser.

Comment: Is Calculation turned off? Check this by going to File->Options->Schedule->Calculation.  (To answer your comment question: stack overflow does not allow posting files).

Comment: Do you have any logic links to or from summary tasks?